# Pause function in slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Edit:**

This is the error i get when I press the button.

[image]

---

I'm using Vegas background slider and I'm trying to add the pause and next function onto my web page. According to the documentation (http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/slideshow/) `$.vegas('next');` and `$.vegas('pause');` should trigger each action. I've tried to do add this below the slider javascript on my webpage:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
$.vegas('pause');
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Pause slideshow</button>
```

But with no successes. Below is the entire slideshow code:

```
<script>
$.vegas('slideshow', { delay: 4000,
    backgrounds: [
        { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
    { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
        { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
        { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
        // { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
        // { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },
    ],
    walk: function(step) {
    //alert('N°' + step + ' is now displayed');

    // get a handle on the sidebar
    var $sidebar = $('div.sidebar');

    // change menu color
    switch (step) {
    case 0: <?php if( get_field('bild1_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    case 1: <?php if( get_field('bild2_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    case 2: <?php if( get_field('bild3_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    case 3: <?php if( get_field('bild4_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    // case 4: <?php if( get_field('bild5_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    // case 5: <?php if( get_field('bild6_gogray', $originalid) ){echo 'goGray($sidebar);' ;}else{echo 'goWhite($sidebar);' ;} ?> break;
    default: goWhite($sidebar); break;
    }
}
})('overlay');

function goGray($sidebar){

$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() > 640) {
    $sidebar.removeClass('white').addClass('gray');
        } else {
    $sidebar.removeClass('white').addClass('gray');

        }
    }).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
});


    $('#logo_white').hide();
    $('#logo_gray').show();

}

function goWhite($sidebar){

$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() > 640) {
        $sidebar.removeClass('gray').addClass('white');
        } else {
        $sidebar.removeClass('gray').addClass('gray');

        }
    }).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
});

    $('#logo_gray').hide();
    $('#logo_white').show();


}


</script>
```

Comment: Could you tell us what errors you get in your JS console? I made a simple JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFs68/2/
Try to extend it with your actual code for us to help you :)

Comment: Your fiddle works great and it seems to me that I'm doing it the same way. Please see updated post where I've posted the error massage.

Comment: I think you just need to remove the "," before // { src: 'IMGSRC', fade: 1000 },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page, you load jQuery twice:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
...
<script src="/wp-content/themes/forsbergform.se/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Remove the second line and it should work.

Comment: You can have a look at ff.felipes.se